# WSO2 API 2.0.0: deployment of sample PizzaShackAPI - hostname in certificate didn't match

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When deploying the sample API over a cluster the deployment is succeeding, however when trying out the API via the API console, the gateway worker is reporting the following SSL exception when connecting to the key manager for key validation.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-26 13:58:00,025] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} -  API authentication failed with error 900900   {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Error while accessing backend services for API key validation

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <wso2_key_manager.service.core.local> != </localhost>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a distributed setup, you can't use default certificates. You should use certificates with proper CNs which match with hostnames.

Comment: So can I use a self signed certificate for testing purposes; and replace the default wso2carbon.jks file ?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to update configurations if you use different keystore name, alias etc.